# Ошибки при снижении нагрузки Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Не подскажете как правильно расчитать время и кол-во пользователей для плавного снижения нагрузки? Так же при повторном запуске одного и того же тест плана (к примеру через 10мин) тоже выходят ошибки, хотя до этого всё проходило без ошибок.
На этапе повышения нагрузки всё работает нормально, при пиковой нагрузке тоже, но когда начинается shutdown начинаются ошибки падать. Пробовал вот такие варианты, все с ошибками идут именно на shutdown. Заранее спасибо за помощь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ошибка" понятие довольно широкое, мы не можем вам помочь не зная что это за "ошибка".

Скорее всего ваше утверждение "всё работает нормально" неверно и когда на этапе "снижения нагрузки" JMeter пытается остановить виртуальных пользователей то соединение с тестируемым приложением завершается некорректно, например, из-за того что виртуальный пользователь не получил ответа на запрос.

Попробуйте выставить таймауты соответствующие вашим NFR/SLA в [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) или [HTTP Request Defaults](https://guides.blazemeter.com/g/the-jmeter-pros-load-testing-checklist/23665)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По поводу ошибок , то выдаёт в основном 502,504. Максимальное время ответа было 44 сек. По вашему совету выставил таймаут сначала на 50с, по итогу макс время после теста 63 сек было, но разве такое долгое время ответа нормальным считается?